# flutter/cloud firestore : How to get only one data from doc?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I use cloud firestore with flutter and I successed to get all key/value from document but I don't successed to match only one id from doc

here is my code:

```
 getgift() async {

    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


    // Get docs from collection reference
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await  firestoreInstance.collection("parrainage").get();

    // Get data from docs and convert map to List
    final mydata= querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toString();

    print("$mydata");
```

my current output is  `({key1: value1}, {key2: value2})`

I trie to match only data from key1 for this exemple.

thank you
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will return a `DocumentSnapshot` object.

```dart
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await firestoreInstance.collection("parrainage").doc("key1").get();
```

You can access its value by doing the following:

```dart
dynamic x = snapshot.data(); // will return value1
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, just have a problem with data() who is highlight in red. error : The methode 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Function'

Comment: Made the necessary change. Please check.

Comment: sorry I don't uderstand , I change with your code, but I can't use because of .data()

Comment: That's cause `.data()` returns a Map, not the value. If you use `.data()[key1]` or `.get[key1]`, it'll give the value, as explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only want to get `value1` to be got. If that's so, then simply do this:

```
final mydata= querySnapshot.docs.firstWhere((element) => element.data().containsKey(key1));
```

Or, if ya want to get only the data with key as `key1` (instead of getting all the keys and values), do this:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await  firestoreInstance.collection("parrainage").doc(key1).get();
final mydata= querySnapshot.get(key1);
```

Cheers

Comment: with this example I have error Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 1570): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 1570): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/flutter ( 1570): 1 
E/flutter ( 1570): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element
E/flutter ( 1570): #0      ListMixin.firstWhere

Comment: Whaa? That error doesn't even seem related to the code...